How to copy pre-built fields from one webform to another
I have two webforms. One form contains a set of pre-built components for handling donations. I'd like to copy these donation-related fields from that form and add them to another webform. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks
Mike

D7 or D8/9/10? In the latter you can potentially copy bits out of yaml and put in to the yaml of the new form

but not clear if you are talking civi fields specifically or just webform elements

if they are civi fields then the logic may be 1/ enable fields in civi, 2/ overwrite them with the pasted yaml

Just webforms and its for D7, although we will be upgrading shortly so good to know about yaml, thanks.

how about cloning the form? or have you already made the other form?
